# What are the best predators to spark intelligence in these aliens?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, environment, ecology

I want my aliens to have some very interesting adaptations, but with these adaptations comes the question "why do they even need intelligence in the first place?". My solution to this is predators. It will make the planet more interesting and add conflict.

So my question is: **What kind of predators would be perfect to cause this creature to evolve human-level sentience and intelligence?**

- their diet consists of decaying organic matter and waste, which is found all over the floor of most of the planet
- they can cause very cold gas to erupt from openings on their bodies, which flash freeze at short range and fog up the atmosphere at long range
- they are slimy
- very good vision with large eyes that would rival pigeons and Mantis Shrimp on earth. Most of their other senses are weak and they have no sense of smell
- around the same size as humans, but weaker with less endurance

Comment: Here is my semi-answer to this. Generally, predators aren't the only thing that causes awareness of surroundings. There is probably a social aspect to it too, and gaining sentience is generally a fuzzy area in biology.

Comment: Intelligence, like any other trait, is selected for on the basis that the parents are better adapted to the environment and so have more offspring than ones who are not as adapted. Given the environment you describe, better adaptations would be the ability to hide, mimic the environment or project even more powerful jets of gas. They are much simpler to select for and have immediate utility for creatures having these mutations.

Comment: Another solution you might like to consider, rather than predators, is social dynamics. It requires intelligence to deal with different individuals and to get them to do what you want, and remember your history with them, and so on. Sort of a chicken-or-egg thing, but there's a strong link between brain size and social group size for monkeys, can read it at https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/social-network-size-linked-brain-size/

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder I understand that peditors aren't the only thing that causes intelligence, but they can be a factor and would be one I can do a lot with for the plot. Plus some experts believe it was snakes which caused intelligence in humans.

Comment: @user45751 source?

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2013/10/did-snakes-help-build-primate-brain

Comment: The predator can help, but not in the way you think. The predator will create the food shortage, so the alien population will have to think of new ways to get food, developing their intelligence.

Comment: You may be in error assuming that beings evolve intelligence to help survive.  On Earth there are many species of mammals with bodies large enough to support large brains.  Some of those large mammals do have large brains and exhibit behavior indicating intelligence ranges that may overlap significantly with the human intelligence range.  It is possible that they evolved large brains to handle sensory input or to control their bodies, etc.,  and that intelligence is a side effect of having those large brains instead of what drives increases in brain size.

Comment: After an edit this was in the reopen queue, but I cannot vote to reopen it.  The problem is that intelligence evolves because of the need to solve problems (aka, problem-solving skills).  What problems do the predators cause?  It needs to be many, since solving but one problem doesn't develop intelligence.  It's more than predators, too.  Changes in the environment, erupting volcanoes or earthquakes, draining a lake of fish and needing to find another... problems... lots of problems = evolution of intelligence.

Answer (score 4):

**Your aliens are their own predators**.

These aliens have food everywhere, but accumulate needed mineral or other resources in their own bodies.  Cannibalism is a good strategy to quickly acquire these resources.  The big ones eat the small ones.  The fast ones eat the slow ones (or bite off big pieces then run).  Team up with your siblings and overpower singletons, then share the meat.

The smarter you are, the better you eat.  Outwit your conspecifics and dine on their succulent flesh.  Be careful of your offspring though.  They might be smarter than you.